# Why can't I upload a new ECC key to key servers, which is supported by GnuPG 2.1?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, pgp, gnupg

My OpenPGP key is soon to expire so I wanted to create a new one.
GPG 2.1 came out a month ago including ECC support and I wanted to try the new key types.

So I have generated a brand new ed25519 key. Today I tried to upload it using `gpg2 --send-key` but then I couldn't find it.
I also uploaded it manually on `pgp.mit.edu` and I got:

```
Key block added to key server database. New public keys added: 
1 key(s) added successfully.
```

but still couldn't find it with a search.

Why? Is it unsupported?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pgp.mit.edu` and most other key servers are currently running the [SKS key server software](https://bitbucket.org/skskeyserver/sks-keyserver/overview), which is (as of November 30th, 2014) [not yet ready for the new ECC keys](https://bitbucket.org/skskeyserver/sks-keyserver/issue/31/support-for-eddsa). There is some code, though; but it is not ready for production yet.

Be aware that even if most keyservers will support it (probably rather soon), broad support for ECC keys with other OpenPGP users will take quite some time, don't expect a majority of GnuPG users to have GnuPG available for their distribution within the next months or even 2-3 years, and people using older implementations will *not* be able to use ECC keys!

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will stick with RSA for a few more.